# What tools to use for a simple API for MySQL on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, api

Suppose I have a MySQL database running on a Debian Linux server and I would like to create a simple API (RESTful) to access data from this database. How would you do this, and what opensource tools would you use?

Please note I'm new to using web services so I'm not exactly sure what extra information to put here, but I'm happy to elaborate in the comments if needed.

Comment: You can use any Programming languages to make a RESTful API.

Comment: How would you host this API though? If you created it using Java, would you use Tomcat to host it?

Comment: Yes, you need a Web Server to Host your API, if you write API in JAVA you need Tomcat or Glassfish Server.

Answer (score 1):

To write a RESTful API you can use any programming languages like Java, PHP, Ruby, Python, NodeJS etc.

Every RESTful application you write needs a Server to test, debug and run either in development or production environment. Therefore, be sure with your task and choose the language you are familiar with and also you can use the frameworks like Laravel, Ruby on Rails, Django, Spring etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many options. You you can pick any of these frameworks for rapid development. The most popular nowadays.

- Express (Javascript)
- Laravel / Cake PHP (PHP)
- Spring Boot (Java)
- Akka HTTP (Scala)
- Django / Flask (Python)